# Regex Expression for Chinese Character Symbols/Punctuations?

Tags: javascript, java, regex, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to post a JSON request to my api endpoint but it is failing because of Chinese brackets which is present in my request. Currently, my request contains:

```
{"name":"聚思（杭州）自动化有限公司"}
```

When I am removing the Chinese brackets `（` `）` and replacing it with normal `(` `)` , I am able to post the request as below:

```
{"name":"聚思 (杭州) 自动化有限公司"}
```

Moreover, I can find that my api code is not able to understand any Chinese character symbols/punctuation, but can understand Chinese alphabets/letters. Currently, the regex expression I am using is this: ^[\w\s~/\@%#$!~^;`*&()_+=[]{}|\,\'.?:<>-]{1,100}$

May I know, how can I modify the above regex expression(or maybe the request before posting to API endpoint) so that my java code does not reject the Chinese symbols/punctuation? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just use the solution from the linked answer to match any Chinese characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hex unicode in a regex to specify non-standard characters:

`\uFF08` is `（` and `\uFF09` is `）`.

```js
var str = "（example）";

str.replace(/\uFF08/g,"(").replace(/\uFF09/g,")");

// => (example)
```